# Is there a limit of the size of data using replaceWIth in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the `replaceWith()` function in jQuery to update my web page.  I receive the data from a C# web service program that extracts data from a database to build my HTML code.  It works fine except when I replace large amounts of data.  In the example that's not working, I replace code in my web page with 39000 bytes of data.  After that, none of my links work when clicking on a span to calls a JavaScript function.  Is there a limit on the size of data used in the `replaceWith()` function?  The html code I am replacing looks like this:

```
<td align=left valign=top>
<div id="showitems" class="showitems" style="display:inline; float:left"></div>
 </td>
```

The javascript code looks like this:

```
function ShowDinerItems() {

            var gps = document.getElementById("selectdiner").value;
            var pos = gps.indexOf(";");
            var len = gps.length;
            var latitude = document.getElementById("Hiddenlat").value;
            var longitude = document.getElementById("Hiddenlng").value;
            var dinerkey = gps.substring(0, pos);
            PageMethods.CallShowDinerItems(dinerkey, latitude,longitude,               OnShowDinerComplete, OnShowDinerError, dinerkey);
        }

    function OnShowDinerComplete(result) {
        var htmlcode = result[0];
        if (result == 'none') {
                document.getElementById("Message").value = "Search returned no items";

            }
            else {
                var htmlcode = result[0];
                htmlcode = "<div id=\"showitems\" class=\"showitems\"         style=\"display:inline\">" + htmlcode + "</div>";
                $('.showitems').replaceWith(htmlcode); // size of htmlcode is 39849 bytes
                var locations = result[1].split(";");
                var lat = locations[0];
                var lng = locations[1];
                markDiner(lat, lng, "", 'map_canvas');

            }
        }
```

The reason I am using jquery to build my webpage is to avoid page reloads.  I could easily program the webdata content in my C# program which may be more efficient but page reloads are to be avoided as dictated by the people who own the website.  I am will try the recommendations given.

Note: I used the following code to make it work.

```
 $('.showitems').html(result[0]);
```

Using .text will not work as it displays raw data and not html data.  Thanks to those who contributed.

Comment: Let's see some of that broken html.

Comment: How are you binding your events? Are you using delegated handlers? Are those delegated handlers on elements being replaced?

Comment: i wouldn't worry about the limit. i would rather worry about the procedure you are using.

Comment: 39000 bytes isn't that much, only 38k, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: hi Dave, how are you getting along with this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I think you're going about this the wrong way here.

It seems to me that you're using ReplaceWith to completely overwrite the matched tag when you could just as simply change its properties with jQuery.

For example:

```
var htmlcode = result[0];
htmlcode = "<div id=\"showitems\" class=\"showitems\"         style=\"display:inline\">" + htmlcode + "</div>";
$('.showitems').replaceWith(htmlcode); // size of htmlcode is 39849 bytes
```

Could easily be changed to this:

```
$('.showitems').css('float','none').text(result[0]);
```

Just how many showItems are there going to be by the way, and how do you know how it compares to how many results you get back from the C# call ?

Edit 2: Sorry, didn't realise that the CSS display attribute wasn't actually changing.

Comment: Also consider that DOM manipulation performance varies across browsers, it's better to just tweak the attributes you need rather then wholesale remove and replace.